# How do I pivot with hour format(HH:HourNumber)?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have OrderInfo table which contains OrderTime(date+time),OrderTrackDate(date),OrderTotal(sales amount) columns as shown in the following image.

**1. Table1(Original Table)**

[image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-B4gIQ0DtFn8/VJSrmb5wHVI/AAAAAAAAAJw/8vo4HypwTyI/w573-h187-no/orderinfoCapture.PNG]

Here is the code I have tried so far before pivoting.

```
SELECT  CAST(DATEPART(DAY, OrderTime) as varchar)+'/'+ CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, OrderTime) as varchar)+'/'+CAST(DATEPART(year,OrderTime) as varchar) as daymonthyear,
ROUND(SUM(OrderTotal),2) AS Sales, COUNT(OrderTotal) AS Orders
,datepart(hour,OrderTime) as HH 
FROM OrderInfo where OrderTime >= '5/24/2013' AND OrderTrackDate <='5/30/2013'
GROUP BY  DATEPART(year, OrderTime),DATEPART(MONTH, OrderTime),DATEPART(day, OrderTime),datepart(hour,OrderTime)
Order By daymonthyear,HH
```

**2. Table 2(Grouped according to Date,Hour from Table1)**

[image]

How do I pivot dynamically and show sales amount per hour based on `Table2`?

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are running into? What does your schema look like? What have you tried?

Comment: We are not here to do your job for you. YOU write the query, we'll maybe try help fix it.

Comment: Love those columns names. Very descriptive.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Looks like he's asking for a dynamic pivot based off of the values of the Hour column.

Comment: the input table has 3 columns. I could not write the query for the desired output. please help me

Comment: @The Head Rush you can ignore the descriptive part

Comment: What happened? @Jahangir Alam

Comment: you edited @Sarath Avanavu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a temp table to use it in 3 places - Select columns for pivot, Replace null with zero and inside pivot.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SUM(ORDERTOTAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(ORDERTIME AS DATE),DATEPART(HH,ORDERTIME)) [TOTAL],
CONVERT(varchar, CAST(ORDERTIME AS datetime), 103) [DATE],
DATEPART(HH,ORDERTIME) [HOUR],
'HH:'+CAST(DATEPART(HH,ORDERTIME) AS VARCHAR(3)) [HOURCOL]
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM ORDERTBL
ORDER BY DATEPART(HH,ORDERTIME)
```

Now declare 2 variables to select columns for pivot and replace null with zero

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @NullToZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [HOURCOL] + ']', 
              '[' + [HOURCOL] + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [HOUR],[HOURCOL] FROM #NEWTABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY [HOUR]

SET @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',ISNULL(['+[HOURCOL]+'],0) AS ['+[HOURCOL]+']' 
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT [HOUR],[HOURCOL] FROM #NEWTABLE GROUP BY [HOUR],[HOURCOL])TAB  
ORDER BY [HOUR]  FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)
```

Now pivot the result

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT [DATE],' + @NullToZeroCols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT [HOURCOL],[TOTAL], [DATE] FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM([TOTAL])
                 FOR [HOURCOL] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f2e05/3)

Comment: I can not up vote since I am a new user, I have learnt something new. Thank you @Sarath Avanavu

Comment: You are welcome. Is this the result you were looking for? If yes and is working, you can mark this answer as correct by checking the tick mark @Jahangir Alam

Comment: No problem. Once you get 15+ reputation, you can vote up :) @Jahangir Alam